# Setup Jupyter inside Fusion's CentOS 7

Tags: linux, macos, centos, jupyter, vmware-fusion

I am trying to install Jupyter inside CentOS 7 VM (that I already had) so I can access it via port 8888 at my host Mac laptop. However, I cannot figure out the networking piece.

**I am changing the IP address to 200.100.x.x for convenience**

**From Host Machine**

I have 2 adapters for that CentOS VM

[image]

[image]

`$ ifconfig` gives me this (I believe those are the same):

```
vmnet1: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 00:50:56:c0:00:01 
    inet 200.100.42.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 200.100.42.255
vmnet8: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 00:50:56:c0:00:08 
    inet 200.100.40.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 200.100.40.255
```

**From within CentOS**

```
[root@localhost ~]# ifconfig
eno16777736: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 200.100.40.145  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 200.100.40.255
        inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:febf:4878  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:0c:29:bf:48:78  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 645  bytes 97963 (95.6 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 215  bytes 24854 (24.2 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eno33554984: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 200.100.42.128  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 200.100.42.255
        inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fe3d:7210  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:50:56:3d:72:10  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 18  bytes 1884 (1.8 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 45  bytes 6130 (5.9 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 220  bytes 50398 (49.2 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 220  bytes 50398 (49.2 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**My tests**

I pinged the following IP addresses from my host machine and they all worked:

```
200.100.42.128

200.100.40.145

200.100.42.1

200.100.40.1
```

That means there is networking connectivity into the VM. Correct?

When I do `jupyter notebook`, I could access `http://localhost:8888/tree` inside the VM **but I cannot go there using any IP address from my host OS on the Macbook.**

I have restarted my VM many times.

**Questions**

1. Is it because of port blocking / not forwarding (8888) or something and if so, how to fix it?
2. Did I setup the networking incorrectly? Is there something else I need to do inside CentOS? I read this blog here http://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Blog/BlogEntry201310x2 and I don't see `eth0` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is Jupyter picked `127.0.0.0` or `localhost` by default. If you have the adapter with other IP addresses, it won't work.

You need to change the IP of Jupyter inside the VM

http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config.html

`$ jupyter notebook --generate-config`

Edit it:

`vi /root/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py`

Then change:

`c.Notebookapp.ip = '0.0.0.0'`

Restart `jupyter notebook` and should be good to go.

Make sure firewall is off or open for port `8888` as well.